# Indexing Django ArrayField or not?

Tags: django, postgresql

Using Django 1.8 on a Postgres 9.6.
One of my model has an ArrayField:

```
packages = ArrayField( models.CharField( max_length = 200 ), blank = True )
```

First question is should I add index to it ?
Documentation says

> At present using db_index will create a btree index. This does not
>   offer particularly significant help to querying. A more useful index
>   is a GIN index, which you should create using a RunSQL operation.

But it's not clear what I should do with that.

If yes, second question, is where to place "db_index = True" ? 
Like so?:

```
packages = ArrayField( models.CharField( db_index = True, max_length = 200 ), blank = True )
```

Comment: so what did you decide on?

Comment: Well following your answer I decided not to search array fields so I didn't added index. I'm a bit disappointed that it's not good practice to use array fields and will avoid them in the future unless i'm absolutely sure I won't need to search in them.

Comment: I am glad I was able to persuade you to do this :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's what the django docs say. This is what the [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) say

> Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a
>   sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row
>   for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to
>   search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.

**should I add index to it ?**
That means you are thinking of searching the array field. Postgresql advises you not to. In fact, you shouldn't really ever store arrays or CSV in a single column. What you should do is to normalize your tables.

**If yes, second question, is where to place "db_index = True" ?**
irreverent because of above.